# How add SQL parameter in OAuth 2.0 Playground with FusioneTables Scope

Tags: google-fusion-tables, oauth2-playground

At [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

is possible test every scope of Oauth.
I have tried https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables .
One of the possible operation is "SQL QUERY".

But, I don't know how insert the SQL paremeter.
If I add it in "add headers" this is the reply:

```
Request / Response

POST /fusiontables/v1/query HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: OAuth ya29.AHES6ZSEoq_cukM3HJmIETXNB5CN4xD1VhUVxhANuYTrLlo7juxMow
Sql: insert into 1d8SL_beOD82al66Xnpb-juHYq8b4WW9m6ORNzsM (Text) values ('casa')
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-length: 249
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
X-google-cache-control: remote-fetch
-content-encoding: gzip
Server: GSE
Reason: Bad Request
Via: HTTP/1.1 GWA
Cache-control: private, max-age=0
Date: Mon, 19 Nov 2012 14:21:33 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Mon, 19 Nov 2012 14:21:33 GMT
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required parameter: sql",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "sql"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required parameter: sql"
 }
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `sql` parameter is a URL parameter and therefore is part of the request URL.

This should work:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=insert+into+1d8SL_beOD82al66Xnpb-juHYq8b4WW9m6ORNzsM+(Text)+values+('casa')
```

Then you have to check the [query API documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference) if which operation uses `GET` and `POST`, in case of an `INSERT` statement use `POST`. Like that [I was able to insert a row using the OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/#step3&scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables&auth_code=4/R436ru0ftdy-OA0TGZwvyfer0VAo.4u8ubZwOmk4WOl05ti8ZT3ZJ6jk5dgI&url=https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=insert%2binto%2b1vdQm0PbPmD4s2GuS34Xm00aTqGCDmI3zafZczCo%2b%28Text%29%2bvalues%2b%28%27casa%27%29&content_type=application/json&http_method=POST&useDefaultOauthCred=unchecked&oauthEndpointSelect=Google&oauthAuthEndpointValue=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth&oauthTokenEndpointValue=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token&expires_in=3599&access_token_issue_date=1353394640&for_access_token=ya29.AHES6ZSd119DpALPTJ3HoTMgxX0Q6tp8-jgu1QmbFpGos3dNmd3TAw&includeCredentials=unchecked&accessTokenType=oauth&autoRefreshToken=unchecked&accessType=offline&forceAprovalPrompt=checked&response_type=code).

To make things easier you might want to check out the [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/fusiontables/v1/).